# how to find a section of current directory path using regex in a bash function

Tags: bash

i need to just find one section of the path to be used as the parent path in a bash script function.

for example

```
cd = /var/www/
pwd = /var/www/alpha/something/somewhere/somewhere
pwd = /var/www/1042/someplace/somehow
```

now i need to find the third section of this path

eg: **migration**, or **1042**

to be the new root so i can tell bash to look for some other child folders no matter where and how deep i'm currently at.

so that if for example im at /8 of alpha/

```
pwd = /var/www/alpha/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8
                        /a/b/c/d/
```

i can issue commands to   */d* quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick one liner to print the directory:

```
pwd | cut -d / -f 4
```

To actually run a command from that directory, use:

```
(cd `pwd | cut -d / -f 1-4`; your-command-here)
```

Comment: what about getting all /var/www/blah/ instead of just /blah/